# Video/article slider.

Tags: javascript

I have created a video/article slider. It works fine, but I have a feeling it's not quite a standard solution.

I would appreciate it if someone could review my code, so that if there are mistakes, I could learn from them.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> 

var move = function slide() {
    $('#container').animate({'marginLeft' : '-=707px'}, 500);
}

 //setInterval(function(){slide()},3000000);

</script> 


<script>

  window.addEventListener("load", function(){

      //slide 1, slide 2
      setTimeout(function(){       
      var video0 = document.createElement('video');
      video0.src = 'images/video/trx.mp4';
      video0.id = 'video0';

      video0.autoplay = true;
      video0.controls = true;

      document.getElementById("vidcont_0").appendChild(video0) 


       slide2();
       },30000);


 });

       //slide 3
       var slide2 = function(){     
       move(); 

       setTimeout(function(){       
       slide3();    
    }, 30000);

}

        //slide 4
        var slide3 = function(){            
        move();  

        setTimeout(function(){ 
        var video1 = document.createElement('video');
        video1.src = 'images/video/trx.mp4';
        video1.id = 'video1';

        video1.autoplay = true;
        video1.controls = true;

        document.getElementById("vidcont_1").appendChild(video1);          
        slide4();

         }, 30000);

}

        //slide 5
        var slide4 = function(){        
        move();        
        setTimeout(function(){      
        slide5();   

       }, 30000);

}


        //slide 6
        function slide5(){          
        move();  

        setTimeout(function(){

        video2 = document.createElement('video');
        video2.src = 'images/video/trx.mp4';
        video2.id = 'video2';

        video2.autoplay = true;
        video2.controls = true;

       document.getElementById("vidcont_2").appendChild(video2);        
       //window.open("http://server.info-spot.net", "_self");    
       slide6();       

      }, 30000);

}

        //slide 7
        var slide6 = function(){    
        move();        
        setTimeout(function(){      

       move();

       }, 30000);

}






</script>
 <style type="text/css">

 body {}
 #wrapper {width:707px; height:820px;overflow:;}
 #container {width:5000px;height:820px;}

#video0 {width:707px; height:820px;float:left;}
#video1 {width:707px;height:820px;float:left;background:##F93;}
#video2 {width:707px;height:820px;float:left;background:#093;}
#video3 {width:707px;height:820px;float:left;background:#F0F;}
#article0 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#999;}
#article1 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#f00;}
#article2 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#06F;}
#article3 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#06F;}

</style>


</head>
<body>



<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">

<div id="article0">Article 0</div>

<div id="vidcont_0"></div> 

<div id="article1">Article 1</div>

<div id="vidcont_1"></div> 

<div id="article2">Article 2</div>

<div id="vidcont_2"></div> 

<div id="article3">Article 3</div>





</div><!----end container---> 
</div>   <!----end wrapper--->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider having the css be in an external css file and javascript in an external js file since there is quite a bit of non-HTML code, but that is just my own preference.

I would get rid of extra **whitespace** and a lot of rework can be done with **indentation** to make the code more readable.

You can also **group variable assignments together**:

```
var video1 = document.createElement('video');
video1.src = 'images/video/trx.mp4';
video1.id = 'video1';
video1.autoplay = true;
video1.controls = true;
```

And **group methods together**:

```
document.getElementById("vidcont_2").appendChild(video2);        
slide6();
```

I would **consolidate <script> tags** that are right next to each other.

**Remove old code** that is commented out if you're not planning on using it.

---

### Reformatted:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

var move = function slide() {
    $('#container').animate({'marginLeft' : '-=707px'}, 500);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){

    //slide 1, slide 2
    setTimeout(function(){
        var video0 = document.createElement('video');
        video0.src = 'images/video/trx.mp4';
        video0.id = 'video0';
        video0.autoplay = true;
        video0.controls = true;

        document.getElementById("vidcont_0").appendChild(video0);
        slide2();

    },30000);
});

//slide 3
var slide2 = function(){     

    move(); 

    setTimeout(function(){       
        slide3();    
     }, 30000);
}

//slide 4
var slide3 = function(){            
    move();  

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var video1 = document.createElement('video');
        video1.src = 'images/video/trx.mp4';
        video1.id = 'video1';
        video1.autoplay = true;
        video1.controls = true;

        document.getElementById("vidcont_1").appendChild(video1);          
        slide4();

         }, 30000);
    }

    //slide 5
    var slide4 = function(){        
    move();        
    setTimeout(function(){      
    slide5();   

    }, 30000);
}

//slide 6
function slide5(){          
     move();  

     setTimeout(function(){
         video2 = document.createElement('video');
         video2.src = 'images/video/trx.mp4';
         video2.id = 'video2';
         video2.autoplay = true;
         video2.controls = true;

         document.getElementById("vidcont_2").appendChild(video2);        
         slide6();       

      }, 30000);
}

//slide 7
var slide6 = function(){    
    move();        
    setTimeout(function(){      
        move();
    }, 30000);
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {}
#wrapper {width:707px; height:820px;overflow:;}
#container {width:5000px;height:820px;}
#video0 {width:707px; height:820px;float:left;}
#video1 {width:707px;height:820px;float:left;background:##F93;}
#video2 {width:707px;height:820px;float:left;background:#093;}
#video3 {width:707px;height:820px;float:left;background:#F0F;}
#article0 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#999;}
#article1 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#f00;}
#article2 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#06F;}
#article3 {float:left;width:707px;height:820px;background:#06F;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="article0">Article 0</div>
        <div id="vidcont_0"></div> 
        <div id="article1">Article 1</div>
        <div id="vidcont_1"></div> 
        <div id="article2">Article 2</div>
        <div id="vidcont_2"></div> 
       <div id="article3">Article 3</div>
    </div><!----end container---> 
</div>   <!----end wrapper--->
</body>

</html>
```

**Additional Note:** I would also improve the **comments** to be more descriptive and helpful.

- `<!----end container--->` is unnecessary if you have proper indentation
- `//slide 5` right before `var slide4` is confusing
- If you keep HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in the same file I would comment each section as such.

Comment: Thank you really much for the suggestions. I have nicely separated the code formats in separate files. Now it is more clear and nice to have only HTML to work with in the index file.